# Behaviorists hate this trick

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>Part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box)</sub>

---

Here's a 3x3 grid

[image]

Here are the nine cells of the grid in no particular order

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Place them correctly, then tell me the final word

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the answer is

> INTROSPECTIONIST  - one who spends a lot of time examining their own thoughts and feelings. This is the opposite of a behaviorist who would want to spend time interacting with others/the environment... explaining the title.

Reasoning: We can

> Count the number of dots in each square to get
>  15,6,14,11,13,12,10,16,8.

It looks like we need to place the squares so that the

> Numbers on the edges are the sums of the dots in that row/column.
>  45 is the highest number and the only way to get there is to put 14,15,16 in the top row.
>  25 is the lowest number and the only way to get there is to put 8,11,6 in the middle row.
>  To get the bottom sums, the final arrangement is:
>  14 16 15
>  8  11 6
>  13 12 10

> Now we can arrange the squares, and then draw lines between the dots of each color group to form letters:
>   [image: introspectionist]
>  Oops it looks like our 'G' can be redrawn as a 'R', andthe || must both be N's (in fact I overlooked the top dots which form 'n' - thanks HolyBlackCat).
>  Leading to the final word, which looks to be our answer: INTROSPECTIONIST!

Comment: Those `||`s look like `П`s, they have dots in the top-middle.

Comment: rot13(Nyfb ab arrq gb erqenj gur 'T' gb 'E', gur terra qbgf qba'g sbyybj gur 'T' funcr ng nyy. Gurl frrz gb fgneg va gur ybjre yrsg pbeare, tb gb gur hccre yrsg pbeare, bar fcnpr gb gur evtug, bar qbja, bar evtug naq bar qbja, perngvat n xvaq bs 'E' funcr.)